# Wordpress background image not displaying - grayed out in Chrome inspector

Tags: css, wordpress

I cannot get this background image to display on the body or any divs at all on my wordpress demo site. I have tried everything from adding !important to the css, to changing the css into an id and class in an effort to get it to display. I also uploaded it to a remote server to see if my local server was the issue, since it worked on the static site before. No matter what I’ve done, it shows as grayed out in the inspector. I’ve even looked on Firefox to see if it was a Chrome issue.

[Image of my Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eENCe.png)

Here is the code I am using:

```
body{
background-image: url(‘wp-content/themes/jjspizza/assets/images/tie-dye_fade.jpg’);
background-size: cover;
font-family: ‘Open Sans’, sans-serif;
}
```

And here is the code on the live server: https://demo.jjs-pizza.com/

I’m sure it’s something incredibly easy, I just don’t know what else to try. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it will work. As a result, it should be like this:

```
background-image: url('../assets/images/tie-dye_fade.jpg');
```

the complete body tag code should look like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../assets/images/tie-dye_fade.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: nice.  don't know my WP pathing like other folks but that is what you should do @Raebow.  I tested this also

Comment: Gosh thank you! I knew it was something super easy. You’re the best!

Comment: I was glad to help, bro `:)`

Answer (score 0):

mostly like above `background-image: url('../assets/images/tie-dye_fade.jpg');` it will work if not remove that "../" so it will be work

```
body {
background-image: url('assets/images/tie-dye_fade.jpg');
background-size: cover;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
```

if style sheet any css folder you have to use `../` else you have to use just like this `assets/images/tie-dye_fade.jpg`

Comment: Thank you! I did end up taking the ../ out and it worked. Ya’ll are awesome!